# Unsigned char std::vector to unsigned char[]?

Tags: c++, stdvector, arrays

Simple question, how does one create a function which takes an `unsigned char std::vector` and spits out an `unsigned char[]` with a `length`. Thanks!

Ah, well it seems my problem was my knowledge of std::vector. I always believed that std::vector did not hold its values in linear fashion. That solves a lot of my problems. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `&v[0]` to get a pointer to the underlying `char[]` and `v.size()` to get the length?  Do you need to copy the data into some other array?  What exactly is your end goal?

Comment: You might have a `data()` method available.  It does the same thing as &v[0], but unfortunately it's not standard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647618.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use: `&v.front()`.

If you need a copy use `std::copy`.

Comment: Or the "STL-sequence-container-requirement-version" `&v[0]`.

Comment: Ya, I think they are equivalent.  I have always preferred the v.front() variant, but I've learnt that &v[0] is more popular.

Comment: The only reason I think it's more popular is that it's the syntax used in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not a one liner, but it's not too bad:

```
 std::vector<unsigned char> v(10);
 unsigned char* a = new unsigned char[v.size()];
 std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
 delete [] a;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of basically taking the safety from it? Never use `new` where you have to explicitly delete it. In this case, you'd use a `vector` and...now you've just moved it from one vector to another.

Comment: @GMan - Dunno, the OP asked, maybe he needs to pass ownership to a legacy API (turns out, no... he just needed `v.front()`)